# Can OpenVINO support (and use) Nvidia GPU?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, intel, openvino

I've recently installed OpenVINO following [this tutorial](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#set-the-environment-variables) and in the beginning it warned me that it doesn't see the graphics card. I assumed that it was talking about Intel HD Graphics (or similar), as I don't have one of these, but I have Nvidia GTX 1080ti.

[image: Warning message]

I haven't seen anyone talking about this and it is not mentioned in the installation guide, but can it even work with Nvidia graphics cards? And if not, what's the point in using OpenVINO?

Comment: OVMS 2022.3 supports NVIDIA GPUs

Comment: I dont get why this question was closed. Its *speciically* about an ML api for python and C.

Answer (score 6):

OpenVINO™ toolkit extends computer vision and non-vision workloads across Intel® hardware, maximizing performance.

OpenVINO™ toolkit is officially supported by Intel hardware only. OpenVINO™ toolkit does not support other hardware, including Nvidia GPU.

For supported Intel® hardware, refer to [System Requirements](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/openvino-toolkit/system-requirements.html).

Comment: You're not really directly answering the question.  You imply that an NVidia GPU won't be supported (because it's not Intel hardware), but this answer doesn't directly say that no hardware *other* than Intel is supported.  (And no, I'm not counting the link.  Stack Overflow answers need to be self-contained.  [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231).  Links are fine, but they need to only support the answer, not be something the answer depends on.)

Comment: If that means the question isn't answerable, then it's not a good question.  Leave a link in a comment if you just want to leave a link.